# How can I calculate the Monero network hashrate?

Tags: hashrate

I've seen [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/987/how-is-the-monero-network-hashrate-calculated-and-how-is-it-different-than-bitco) but unfortunately it doesn't contain an answer to my question.

The question is: how can I calculate actual hashrate of the whole network? As far as I understand, it depends on difficulty in some way but I can not understand that dependency.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The hash rate can only be estimated from the difficulty, which is itself adjusted up and down based on how fast blocks are found compared to the 120 second target. This estimation is the difficulty (currently 7462457559) divided by the target (currently 120 seconds), so currently about 62 MH/s.

Comment: Great, thank you. And what is the magic number 120? Is this target hardcoded somewhere in Monero software or it depends on some conditions in external world?

Comment: Moneros network tries to maintain 120 second block times (its block target) so the difficulty adjusts dynamically based on the MH/s of the network.

Comment: @ValeryRyaboshapko Yes it's hardcoded - you can find it in the `DIFFICULTY_TARGET_V2` constant in the [code](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/cryptonote_config.h#L75).