# How to create my own miner?

Tags: cpu-mining, development

I am thinking to create my own miner for Monero just for research purpose and understand how is the mining process.

First of all, I red the [cn008 document](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns008.txt) and I understand almost everything but I don't know what should I put in the input string.

In the other hand, I also red the [cn010 document](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns010.txt) but I don't know how is related with cn008 document. I think that DiffCut is (or is related with) the maturity which can be see in every single pool.

Please, can someone help me to understand all of this that apparently is unrelated? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 4):

There's already some answer here: [Where can I find a description of the CryptoNight hash algorithm?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1110/where-can-i-find-a-description-of-the-cryptonight-hash-algorithm)

Here's a schematic of CryptoNight algorithm:[image: CryptoNight] [Source](http://da-data.blogspot.hr/2014/08/minting-money-with-monero-and-cpu.html)

In the node software, the hash function is called `cn_slow_hash`, see [here](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/crypto/slow-hash.c#L519). Also, there's a JavaScript [implementation as well](https://xmr.llcoins.net/slowhash.html) which may be easier to study.

Looking into code of some existing miners should help you as well:

https://github.com/OhGodAPet/wolf-xmr-miner/releases

https://github.com/fireice-uk/xmr-stak-cpu/releases

https://github.com/xmrig/xmrig/releases

Comment: I saw the image and the first link, i have already understood how the CryptoNight's algorithm works. But, How is related the CryptoNight's algorithm with the [cn010](https://cryptonote.org/cns/cns010.txt) (rate of generated blocks)?

Comment: rate of generated blocks will determine the difficulty of the PoW you have to produce for it to be accepted as solution. For a pool miner it shouldn't matter since you get a target PoW difficulty from the pool anyway, and the daemon handles the rest on the pool side AFAIK. Here's some more info: https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/987/how-is-the-monero-network-hashrate-calculated-and-how-is-it-different-than-bitco